# How to properly set ImageView in a UITableViewCell with SDWebImage in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, sdwebimage

I'm new to Swift and iOS and have a situation where I would like to take an array of URL strings and populate a ImageView within a UITableViewCell, which I have made an appropriate class for, called MyTableViewCell.

It's crashing and I am getting the error:

```
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

Which I can see is happening in the viewDidLoad() when the line `imageTableView.datasource = self` runs.

I am setting the data and delegate in the view as so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imagesTableView.dataSource = self
    imagesTableView.delegate = self
}
```

Below, `imageUrls` is an array of Strings.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrls[indexPath.row]))

    return cell
}
```

I have an outlet to the cell like so in the class:

```
@IBOutlet var imagesTableView: UITableView!
```

My question is, what is the proper way to do this with swift 3 and SDWebImage, and why/where is the nil value from the imagesTableView occurring?

It may be worth noting that I have also tried hard-coding some string URL values into the imageUrls to ensure that that was not the problem (I get the same error with hardcoded values).

Comment: how are you creating the view controller?  If you don't create it from the storyboard the outlets won't be set.    Also variables and properties should start with a lower case letter by convention

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the naming convention tip, just fixed some of that up above. I am creating the view controller from the storyboard. If I remove the table view code, the rest of the view loads fine with no errors

Comment: Have you connected the outlet?

Comment: @Paulw11 yep, the imageView is connected as an outlet to the MyTableViewCell class, and the imagesTableView is connected as an outlet in the view controller as shown above.

Comment: Well, th exception tells you the tableview is nil, so either you haven't connected the outlet or you aren't creating the view controller correctly

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, thanks again - I completely deleted and reconnected the whole tableview and subviews and got rid of the error, although I had the outlet before. I did notice the grey icon was missing from the side of the outlet previously, I wonder if this may have had an affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that although I had an outlet connected, it somehow lost the reference - I deleted the whole tableview and subviews and recreated and connected them, and the error was gone. Something funky must have happened when I drag and dropped for the outlet previously.